# Is there a way to tag folders with colors?

Tags: nautilus

I have a projects folder where some of the projects are mere legacy project. Is there a way to give them colors, like you can in Mac OS X?

With Dolphin, I used the various colored folder icons, but there is nothing like that installed on my system for nautilus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do very easily within nautilus, is to give them emblems, I agree, not quite as immediately recognisable but nonetheless a visual way of telling the difference between them.

- Right-click on the folder, and click
  **Properties**.

[image]

- Select the **Emblems** tab.

[image]

- From here, you can add your choice of
  emblems to the folder's icon.

  *(Do note that they change
  to match the emblem style of your icon theme.)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a start, but I cannot find any icons that look good. Additionally, they are not displayed right on my system for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround using Nautilus Actions and Emblems:
http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/2011/05/06/using-nautilus-emblems-like-color-labels-on-mac-os-x